# Sql(Server) NULL or empty string still here

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query

```
SELECT Ets_Se_Categorie AS Ets_Se_Categorie,COUNT(Ets_Se_Categorie) AS cpte
FROM TableV_MyTest
GROUP BY Ets_Se_Categorie
```

It gives me the following table / results

```
Ets_Se_Categorie                                            cpte
(Seems to be empty string)                                  5531
Old place                                                   8
Secondary                                                   1066
Principal                                                   4713
Subsidiary                                                  7985
First                                                       9
headquarter                                                 31610
Main Headquarter                                            1587
```

The `(Seems to be empty string)` means it is an empty field

Aim is to have this

```
Ets_Se_Categorie                                            cpte
Old place                                                   8
Secondary                                                   1066
Principal                                                   4713
Subsidiary                                                  7985
First                                                       9
headquarter                                                 31610
Main Headquarter                                            1587
```

I've created this query

```
 SELECT *
 FROM
 (
 SELECT Ets_Se_Categorie AS Ets_Se_Categorie,COUNT(Ets_Se_Categorie) AS cpte
 FROM TableV_MyTest 
 GROUP BY Ets_Se_Categorie
 ) AS A
 WHERE (A.Ets_Se_Categorie IS NOT NULL OR A.Ets_Se_Categorie != '')
```

Issue is nothing has changed ...

Why did I use a nested query?

I tried this, first

```
 SELECT Ets_Se_Categorie,COUNT(Ets_Se_Categorie) AS cpte
 FROM TableV_MyTest 
 WHERE (Ets_Se_Categorie IS NOT NULL OR Ets_Se_Categorie != '')
 GROUP BY Ets_Se_Categorie
```

Nothing happened...

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Probably very simple but I'm bit confused on the why.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps `Ets_Se_Categorie` is not an empty string, but instead whitespace?  You could try trimming it -- something like `where ltrim(rtrim(Ets_Se_Categorie)) != ''`

Comment: You want rows where the column is not null `AND` its not `''` (i.e. change from `OR` to get what you want)

Comment: I just noticed, you are using `OR` instead of `AND` in your query to attempted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used `OR` instead of `AND`, this should work:

```
WHERE (A.Ets_Se_Categorie IS NOT NULL AND A.Ets_Se_Categorie != '')
```

Since there was confusion about why the `OR` didn't work as expected:

Both conditions must be `true` to return a record. All records are either `NOT NULL` or `!= ''`. Consider a record with an empty string, this record is `NOT NULL`, so it is returned.

Why you didn't see the `NULL` records:

`NULL` is not a valid value, it means *undefined*. So nothing is either equal or unequal to `NULL`. Neither `NULL = NULL`  nor `Anything != NULL` is `true`. You have to use `IS (NOT) NULL`.

In your original query you've filtered out the `NULL` values:

```
 SELECT Ets_Se_Categorie,COUNT(Ets_Se_Categorie) AS cpte
 FROM TableV_MyTest 
 WHERE (Ets_Se_Categorie IS NOT NULL OR Ets_Se_Categorie != '')
 GROUP BY Ets_Se_Categorie
```

because a `NULL` would neither be `NOT NULL` nor `!= ''`(remember last section).

Conclusion: either use `IS NOT NULL AND != ''` or `ISNULL(Column, '') != ''` or `COALESCE(Column, '') != ''` which is ANSI sql (works in all databases).

Comment: @AndyK: because both conditions must be true to return this record. All records are either `NOT NULL` or `!= ''`. Consider you have a `NULL` record, this record is  `!= ''`, so it is returned. Consider a record with an empty string, this record is `NOT NULL`, so it is returned. So the `OR` is causing your issue.

Comment: fair enough. However, if the record is `!= ''` , should it not return the record too?

Comment: Yes, but not if it is `NULL`. You always need **both** conditions to be true. So use `AND`

Comment: You could also simplify this to simply A.Ets_Se_Categorie > '' It will only return values that are not null and have a value other than empty string.

Comment: I read your comment and it starts to sink in. One last question though: If there was a `NULL` or an `''` , why the count did not see it and put it as a NULL? TIA @tim-schmelter

Comment: @AndyK: what means "the count did not see it"? In your question you have count=5531 for empty strings, haven't you?

Comment: I reformulate my question @TimSchmelter : Why did I not have a count for the `NULL` too? Sorry I'm asking a lot of questions because some part of it are not clicking into me , yet. I don't like to give up until I know it is spot on

Comment: @AndyK: i guess because there are no records with NULL values. Otherwise you would see it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter if it is the case then the `Ets_Se_Categorie != ''` should do the exclusion... or Am I missing something because I'm too *umb (d or n : take your pick :) )

Comment: @AndyK: hmm, that's true. Difficult to answer without sample data  :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I've seen that before but nobody has been able to tell me on the reason why. I'll put a question on one of the math forum ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101193/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-andy-k).

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms184325.aspx) instead. Like this:

`WHERE ISNULL(A.Ets_Se_Categorie, '') != ''`

Comment: very elegant! I love it @tom-chantler

Comment: or with ANSI SQL `COALESCE(A.Ets_Se_Categorie, '') != ''`

Comment: Yep, that's true Tim. Whilst the question is tagged as Microsoft SQL Server specific, you're right that `COALESCE` is the ANSI answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `LTRIM, RTRIM` to remove spaces

```
 SELECT 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Ets_Se_Categorie))
    ,COUNT(LTRIM(RTRIM(Ets_Se_Categorie))) AS cpte
 FROM TableV_MyTest 
 WHERE 
    (Ets_Se_Categorie IS NOT NULL AND LTRIM(RTRIM(Ets_Se_Categorie)) != '')
 GROUP BY 
       LTRIM(RTRIM(Ets_Se_Categorie))
```

Comment: All this does is making the query slower LTRIM(RTRIM(Ets_Se_Categorie)) != '' is exactly the same as LTRIM(Ets_Se_Categorie) != '' which is even exactly the same as  Ets_Se_Categorie != ''. Example comparing no space with space returns 0 rows: SELECT 1 WHERE '' != ' '

Answer (score 1):

Try to check spaces in your column.

```
SELECT Ets_Se_Categorie AS Ets_Se_Categorie,COUNT(Ets_Se_Categorie) AS cpte
FROM TableV_MyTest
WHERE LEN(ISNULL(Ets_Se_Categorie, '')) <> 0
GROUP BY Ets_Se_Categorie
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AND here.  It is still returning because it looks and sees that the column is not NULL and returns it.  That's how an OR works, it returns if the first clause is true.

```
 SELECT Ets_Se_Categorie,COUNT(Ets_Se_Categorie) AS cpte
 FROM TableV_MyTest 
 WHERE (Ets_Se_Categorie IS NOT NULL AND Ets_Se_Categorie != '')
 GROUP BY Ets_Se_Categorie
```